# 6 ohm stereo enclosed speakers

Tags: audio

I am making a Raspberry Pi project that I need to add sound to.

I salvaged a pair of 6 Ω stereo enclosed speakers from a Smart TV. Is there any way to hook these up to a RasPi? I am assuming I would need an amplifier of some sort since the built in audio output on the Raspberry Pi uses a 3.5 mm jack and wouldn't be compatible with the plug on these speakers.

I saw an amplifier on Adafruit that uses the same type of speaker plug but it also uses pins. All my pins are being used by the resistive touchscreen for this project. Is it possible to replace the  3.5 mm audio jack with an amplifier/stereo enclosure jack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3.5mm jack provides a line level stereo output. Just get yourself a little amplifier [like this](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/28-12812). It is even on sale at the moment.

Or if you have an old pair of amplified PC speakers laying around, they would work, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer MartinMarty. one question.... i see the JST jack where the speakers plug in, but how does the signal get from the board to the amp?

Comment: 3.5mm stereo cable, M-M, see input jack right in the front of the picture of amplifier.

Comment: I just received the amp and male / male cable. The amp does require soldering. I'll try my best and hope not to screw it up!